# Interior, Exterior and Boundary proofs in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: general-topology, proof-writing

What's the general form for proving Interior, Exterior and Boundary points in two dimensions? Using the open ball $B(x,r)$.

E.g. for the set $\{(x, y) ∈ \mathbb{R}^2 : |x| ≤ 1, y ≥ 0\}$?

I know it's a "generalisation" of the $\mathbb{R}$ version to $\mathbb{R}^2$, but the cross products are causing some difficulties.

Comment: In $\Bbb R^n$, for subsets given the way your set is, the set of interior points is usually acquired by changing all $\geq$ and $\leq$ to $>$ and $<$ respectively (and keeping those that already are $>$ or $<$ without changing them). The set of boundary points you usually get by changing all inequalities to equalities (and some logical mumbo-jumbo, changing AND's to OR's at strategic places). Other than that, it's more often than not a matter of drawing the set and examine it to see what the answer must be.

Answer (score 1):

A neighbourhood of $x$ in $\mathbb R^2$ is an open ball centered at $x$ with radius $r$, denoted by $B(x,r)$.

$x_1$ is said to be an interior point of $A$ if $x_1$ has a neighbourhood that is contained in $A$.

In other words, if you want to prove that $x_1$ is an interior point, then you should guess for a radius $r_1$. After that, you should prove that the open ball centered at $x_1$ with radius $r_1$ is contained in $A$.

$x_2$ is an exterior point of $A$, if $x_2$ is an interior point of $A^c$.

$x_3$ is a boundary point if every neighbourhood of $x_3$ has elements both from $A$ and $A^c$.

**For your example:** For example $(1,3)$ is a boundary point, because whatever $r$ you choose $B\big( (1,3),r \big)$ contains elements from both $A$ and $A^c$.

$(1- \frac r 2 , 3) \in A$ and also this point is in $B\big( (1,3),r \big)$.

However, $(1+ \frac r 2 , 3) \in A^c$ and also this point is in $B\big( (1,3),r \big)$.

So, you can see that whatever $r$ we choose, the open ball around $(1,3)$ with radius $r$ contains elements from both $A$ and $A^c$. Hence $(1,3)$ is a boundary point.

Comment: Put $y$ instead of $3$ and let $y \geq 0$. The proof will still be valid. Then you will consider the points $(-1,y)$ for the boundary ($y \geq 0$), the proof will be similar. Finally, you will prove for the points $(x,0)$ where $-1 \leq x \leq 1$ and thus you will have all the boundary of your set.

Answer (score 0):

$\{(x, y) ∈ \mathbb{R}^2 : |x| < 1, y > 0\}$ are interior point.

$\{(x, y) ∈ \mathbb{R}^2 : |x| = 1, y > 0\}\cup \{(x, y) ∈ \mathbb{R}^2 : |x| \leq 1, y = 0\}$  are boundary point.

exteror points are $\{(x, y) ∈ \mathbb{R}^2 : |x| > 1, y > 0\}\cup \{(x, y) ∈ \mathbb{R}^2 : y<0\}$

Comment: I'm referring to the "open ball" definition and proofs using the open ball. Should've probably said that.

Comment: But that's not the set of boundary points. This is the set of boundary points:
$$
\{(x, y) \in \Bbb R^2 : (|x| = 1, y > 0) \text{ OR } (|x|\leq 1, y = 0)\}
$$

Comment: yea, you are right.